how to use geometric nodes to deform geometry instances with curves?
I followed this tutorial, but ran into a problem creating instances.
What I want to do:
I want the geometry nodes to create instances of the object I place as a reference and deform it along curves.

What is the problem:
When creating a new curve, a new instance is not created.

I know that using the curve index, you can choose which specific curve to deform the object with.
And I tried adding a few nodes at the beginning of the path so that they would create instances and convert them into real geometry.
Before

After

but from the results it becomes clear that without influencing the “index” parameter of the sample curve node, all created instances will simply be deformed along one curve, and I need each created instance to be deformed by the corresponding curve.
And I can’t figure out what and how to connect so that each new curve creates a new instance of the object and deforms it.
Just in case, I'll give you a link to the source file if it helps in any way.

When the tutorial is doing what you want to do, could it be you just made a mistake while recreating it?

I achieved what I wanted and it even seems to work correctly.
And so, in order to indicate the index of the curve, we need to take the “Capture Atribute” node and at the same time install it in the right place, otherwise it will not work.
What changed

what does it look like now?

